# How to hide the top layout guide in a UIWebView in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is a problem I am facing in portrait mode. The `UIWebView` is in fullscreen and the title bar is not starting from the screen size.

I want to hide the little portion which shows battery, and time status. This portion shows after scrolling the web view.

I have used this code:

```
NSLog(@"loadWebView1");
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view = contentView;

//set the web frame size
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
webFrame.origin.y = 0;

//add the web view
theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
theWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
theWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
theWebView.delegate = self;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theWebView loadRequest:req];
[self.view addSubview: theWebView];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide it for a single view the you can do it like this

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return true;
}
```

if you want to hide it for all the views then you can do from TARGETS

check the Hide status bar checkmark

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome. also try to check the right answers as well if any has worked

Answer (score 0):

Set "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" to "**true**" in **Info.plist**.

Then, place the following code in the desired view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return true
}
```